# Mapping Source Collection's Id to Destination Objects Collection Id

Tags: c#, automapper

Suppose in the source object I have classes:

```
// Source classes
class Source
{
   public Source
   {
      things = new List<Thing>();
   }

   public Guid SourceId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Thing> Things { get; set; }
}

class Thing
{
  public Guid ThingId { get; set; }
  public double Price { get; set; }
}

//Destination class
class Dest
{
    public Guid DestId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Guid> ThingsIds { get; set; }
}
```

How do I map Things -> ThingId (src) to ThingsIds (dest) using Automapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the LINQ extension method `.Select`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.ThingsIds, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Things.Select(th => th.ThingId)));
```